# cygwin - irssi not connecting and screen capturing c-a

Tags: emacs, cygwin, gnu-screen, irssi

I've got two questions regarding cygwin usage.

1. I'm trying to run Irssi using Cygwin but it won't connect to any server i give it even if I can connect from other, non-cygwin clients like mIRC and freenode's webchat. The connection always times out and its the same way with other programs (like naim) as well. I can't help but feel that I've missed something, but I don't know what. Do I need to do anything special with Cygwin before I can connect?
2. I use screen to manage multiple windows, but when I'm using screen with Emacs I can't move to the beginning of a line with C-a because that's captured by screen (c-a 0-9 to move to another window, etc). Is there any way to rebind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you running Windows' (or another) firewall on your system?  Have you created exceptions for Irssi in the firewall control panel?
2. You can always send Emacs a literal C-a by typing <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>.  Screen gets the ^A and the following "a" tells screen to send ^A to the terminal.
   Additionally, there are two ways to change Screen's command character (aka escape character).

   - **One-time use: commandline option**
     To change the command character for one Screen session, use the `-e xy` option when starting your screen session.  The default is `-e^Aa`, where `x` is the command character (`^A`) and `y` is the character generating a literal command character (`a`).  If you want your new command character to be `^B`, for example, use `-e^Bb` in your commandline.
   - **Personalized default: ~/.screenrc**
     To change the command character default, specify it in your ~/.screenrc file.  Just add this line to your ~/.screenrc, and your next new session will use the new default command character:

     ```
     escape ^Bb
     ```

     This follows the same `xy` syntax as the commandline option.  You can also use the keyword "defescape" instead of "escape"; they are synonymous.